# Formula to get the right elimination of data on 2 groups

Tags: c++

I have been working for a part of my program which suppose to eliminate/delete items which has a contradicting type with the same values. Here is an example.

Group A.

Symbol     Type      Volume.

EURUSD     Buy       10.

EURUSD     Buy       2.

EURGBP     Buy       10.

Group B

Symbol     Type     Volume.

EURUSD     Sell     2

EURUSD     Sell     5

EURGBP     Sell     10

There are 2 EURUSD on Group A and also 2 EURUSD on Group B. We cannot easily eliminate the first item EURUSD since it has a volume 10 while in Group B the value of first EURUSD is at 2. We easily get the difference on it given that in the Group A item has a larger volume which leaves:

Group A

Symbol     Type      Volume

EURUSD     Buy       8

EURUSD     Buy       2

EURGBP     Buy       10

Group B

Symbol     Type     Volume

EURUSD     Sell     5

EURGBP     Sell     10

same thing here. since EURUSD on Group A is larger than the EURUSD on Group B, we subtract again and eliminate.

Group A

Symbol     Type      Volume

EURUSD     Buy       5

EURUSD     Buy       2

EURGBP     Buy       10

Group B

Symbol     Type     Volume

EURGBP     Sell     10

and since there is no EURUSD left on Group B, we can proceed with the other symbol EURGBP and since they have the same volume as the EURGBP on Group B, we can easily eliminate both which brings us:

Group A

Symbol     Type      Volume

EURUSD     Buy       8

EURUSD     Buy       2

Group B

Symbol     Type     Volume

and that leaves us with only 2 remaining items both EURUSD with 8 and 2 respectively.

I have tried this on but i cannot get the results that i want.

Do you have any formula, algorithm that you can share or examples perhaps.

Thank you very much.

Comment: it looks like basic math: substraction. did I miss something?

Comment: that's what i though also. It is simple when it has only few data.

Comment: you just need a good data structure - a map/dictionary.